# Android class for managing fragment 'pages' outside of tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm creating a data entry application, which is currently divided into three Activities - a login activity, a 'main' activity (user information, summaries, etc), and a data entry activity for a single record. Each of these activities has several different 'screens' (i.e. full-page layouts containing a set of views), and each of those screens is a single fragment.

I have two questions:

1. Is this an appropriate overall architecture? The division of activities/fragments is somewhat arbitrary but these partitions make semantic sense to me.
2. What is the best way to manage switching between fragments within an activity? My main activity uses a `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` since it is based on a tabs + swipe navigation structure, but all activities will have fragments which are not represented as menu items. Should I use a `FragmentPagerAdapter` without a `ViewPager` for this (and if so, how)? Should I be writing my own abstraction layer to handle the transitions?

I've read a number of tutorials and examples but haven't seen this particular pattern used. As I'm not very experienced in Android development, I thought it best to ask whether there's a ready-made solution before I try to write my own. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**: Here's what I have at the moment, as a very simplified version to switch between two 'screens' - a title page and a login page. This shows most of the things I want it to handle (holding fragment instances, managing transactions, placing them into the layout). Still seems like it's replicating the functionality of the PagerAdapter and ViewPager in some ways but I don't want it to be tied to menus, tabs, swiping, etc. since the primary navigation will be through buttons within the app. I'll also need to pass some initial data to the fragment initialization for more complex fragments.

```
public class LoginFragmentSwitcher {
    private int mCurFragIndex;
    private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragList;

    public LoginFragmentSwitcher() {
        //set initial index
        mCurFragIndex = 0;

        //create fragments
        mFragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        mFragList.add(new TitleFragment());
        mFragList.add(new LoginFragment());
        //TODO: more fragments will be added here

        //display the first fragment
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, mFragList.get(0));
        ft.commit();
    }

    // Perform a fragment transition to the specified index
    public void showFragment(int newFragIndex) {
        //only switch if you're not already showing the appropriate fragment
        if (newFragIndex != mCurFragIndex) {
            //start the fragment transaction
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            //TODO: apply transition style if desired

            //switch content to the new fragment
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragList.get(newFragIndex));

            //register entry in the back stack and complete transaction
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

            //update index
            mCurFragIndex = newFragIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Each of these activities has several different screens, and each of those screens is a single fragment" -- while that probably means something to you, it will not mean much to anyone else, as only you know what you mean by a "screen" in this context. You also fail to indicate how these "screens" are represented to the user, how the user switches between them (if applicable), etc.

Comment: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu?source=c  install this app and take the time to go thru all of his samples. there are good viewpager examples w/ sliding menu as well.

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean 'screens' from the user perspective, as a full page layout of elements (edited for clarity). They will switch between them in different ways (but generally not with tabs), thus my question as to whether there's a more general fragment paging class.

Comment: "They will switch between them in different ways" -- that is not especially informative. "whether there's a more general fragment paging class" -- no.

Comment: @CommonsWare I guess I don't see how the specific user action is relevant, since I want something decoupled from the UI. If there isn't such a class, and I just need to write my own, that's an acceptable answer.

Comment: Things that manage fragments are usually tied to how the user manipulates them. `FragmentTabHost` does something different than `ViewPager`, which does something different than you might do with tabs in the action bar, and so on. "I just need to write my own" -- I suspect that you're going to find that there's not much code in it, and that more of the code winds up in whatever is actually displaying the fragments and responding to whatever change mechanism you use.

Comment: @CommonsWare You may be right and I'm not asserting that I even have the correct approach here. When I said 'decoupled from the UI' I meant not tied to a specific tab, menu, or list. I've posted some code that might clarify what I'm attempting.